# C# getting specific elements from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I get specified elements from this XML file?
Let's say I only want the sub11, sub12, etc parts in the end of the tag that might contain SUB**, nothing or something else from each tag into an array?

Also, how could I get the Ex Name with each tag even while there are two Tags under one Ex?
If I'm writing a row to list i would want Ex name then all tag info after that.
Like for first row example:
test1, Subject1, SUB11, 80, SUB12, 31, SUB13, 2
example output of the first EX in to list row.
Second one should be like:
test2, Subject2, SUB21, 100, SUB22, 20, SUB23, 0
Third one:
test2, Subject3, SUB31, etc...

I have real experience with getting data from xml files. So I have no idea how to target spesific parts, even thou searching for hours on how to target xml nodes, child nodes, etc etc did not find what I wanted.

```
<Folder>
   <Ex>
      <Name>test1</Name>
      <Tags>
         <TagEx>
            <Name>Subject1</Name>
            <Tag Type="Maximum" Score="80" ExxTag="no">SUB11</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Average" Perc="31" ExxTag="no">SUB12</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Status" Results="2" ExxTag="no">SUB13</Tag>
         </TagEx>
      </Tags>
   </Ex>
   <Ex>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <Tags>
         <TagEx>
            <Name>Subject2</Name>
            <Tag Type="Maximum" Score="100" ExxTag="no">SUB21</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Average" Perc="20" ExxTag="no">SUB22</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Status" Results="0" ExxTag="no">SUB23</Tag>
         </TagEx>
      </Tags>
      <Tags>
         <TagEx>
            <Name>Subject3</Name>
            <Tag Type="Maximum" Score="10" ExxTag="no">SUB31</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Average" Perc="50" ExxTag="no">SUB32</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Status" Results="3" ExxTag="no">SUB33</Tag>
         </TagEx>
      </Tags>
   </Ex>
</Folder>
```

I have tried a few ways but I end up getting empty values something totally different.

**EDIT:** As requested i can provide what I tried but it does not help in this case as its mostly irrelevant as I want targeting of certain not all as I do it now but here it goes:

```
        var xmldoc = XDocument.Load(ExFile);

        foreach (var name in xmldoc.Descendants("TagEx").Elements()
                            .Select(x => new {
                                Value = x.Value,
                                Type = x.Attribute("Type"),
                                Score = x.Attribute("Score"),
                                Perc = x.Attribute("Perc"),
                                Rest = x.Attribute("Results"),
                                ExxTag = x.Attribute("ExxTag")
                            }))

    {

        if (name.Score != null)
        {
            DScore = name.Score.ToString();
    AScore.Add(ClearSTR(DScore));
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < AType1.Count; i++)
        {
        string[] row = { etc[i],AScore[i],etc[i],etc[i],etc[i],etc[i]};
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
        ListViewData.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }
```

**EDIT2:** *I solved it by just collecting all of the xml data instead of picking what I want and then sorting them with loops by order of receiving items and by possibilities in what the values may hold. It works perfectly, but its not what I wanted. I just wanted to target pick what i want. So I wont add this as solution as I would still love to know how to target pick things from xml.*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please show us the ways that you tried? We're a code fixing service, not a code writing service.

Comment: You could try to use XSLT to transform this XML to a representation that fits your needs, then deserialize the result. For example transform to `<root><Tag><Name></Name><Value></Value></Tag><Tag> ... </Tag></root>` and your model would be a List of a model class with properties "Name" and "Value".

Comment: Show what did you try? We don't know what you want, values sub11 sub12 are not in every tag.

Comment: Just make a new class and deserialize them with XML deserialzation.. Easy and simple

Comment: @Fabio I think OP was referring to the text content of the "Tag" Node.

Comment: @Fildor, that is the point - we shouldn't guess. Why somebody would expect other people to make an effort to answer to the question without an effort to make question clearer

Comment: @Fabio While I generally agree with your statement, it is rather clear (at least to me) in this specific case. But yes, OP should probably rephrase that.

Comment: @Fildor, by effort I mean that from the question we can see that there was no effort to try or search for the answer first. Search for "c# retrieve value from xml" will  provide enough information event to mark this question as duplicate ;)

Comment: @Fabio I see where you're coming from. Given OP's reps, I am tempted to grant some "rookie bonus", though. Sometimes all you need is a push into the right direction ...

Comment: @Enigmativity I did not add what i did as its kinda irrelevant to what i want i just want o know how to target I don't know how to target soo that's the problem i cannot really write the targeting as i don't know how to do it. And if I don't know how to search it on google i cant find what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data =
    from ex in XDocument.Parse(source).Root.Elements("Ex")
    let exname = ex.Element("Name").Value
    from tags in ex.Elements("Tags")
    let tagex = tags.Element("TagEx")
    let tagexname = tagex.Element("Name").Value
    let maximum =
        from tag in tagex.Elements("Tag")
        where tag.Attribute("Type").Value == "Maximum"
        select new [] { tag.Value, tag.Attribute("Score").Value }
    let average =
        from tag in tagex.Elements("Tag")
        where tag.Attribute("Type").Value == "Average"
        select new [] { tag.Value, tag.Attribute("Perc").Value }
    let status =
        from tag in tagex.Elements("Tag")
        where tag.Attribute("Type").Value == "Status"
        select new [] { tag.Value, tag.Attribute("Results").Value }
    let xs = maximum.Concat(average).Concat(status).SelectMany(x => x)
    select new [] { exname, tagexname, }.Concat(xs);
```

I get:

```
test1, Subject1, SUB11, 80, SUB12, 31, SUB13, 2
test2, Subject2, SUB21, 100, SUB22, 20, SUB23, 0
test2, Subject3, SUB31, 10, SUB32, 50, SUB33, 3
```